# Google analytics in phonegap (cordova 2.9)

Tags: cordova

How to improve a website's performance using google analytics in phonegap?
cordova 2.9  and environment : android 4.1.2.

Comment: Refer this - http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/3/28/Google-Analytics-and-PhoneGap

Comment: thanks Suhas for this reference.but I've already tried this.It didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to add simple google Analytics setup then its quite easy just follow the below steps

1:- Add libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar  in libs folder
2:- Add analytics.xml file inside res->values, it binds the trackingid with the app,u can google for this file
3:-Add import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.easyTracker; in the activity file and use EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); in onCreate function.

Thats it, you are done with Google Analytics basic setup